# VPC SC Service Perimeter handle Google Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-vpc

I have a service perimeter created on projects holding Cloud Composer.

The VPC SC Logs snippet are below,

```
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service-org-<ORG_ID>@security-center-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "private",
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "compute.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "compute.beta.DisksService.Insert",
"resourceName": "projects/<CloudComposerProjectNumber>",
"violationReason": "RESOURCES_NOT_IN_SAME_SERVICE_PERIMETER",
"egressViolations": [
        {
          "source": "projects/<CloudComposerProjectNumber>",
          "sourceType": "Resource",
          "servicePerimeter": "accessPolicies/number/servicePerimeters/perimeter_name",
          "targetResource": "projects/<ProjectNumbernotfound>"
        }
      ]
```

I feel the error is because I don't have any access level defined for these Google Owned Service Accounts.
But since the violation reason is NOT_IN_SAME_SERVICE_PERIMETER I don't think that is the reason.
The target project number is not found in my estate. Could it be external or google owned?
I tried adding egress rule for identity "service-org-<ORG_ID>@security-center-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com" but it is failing `Error 400: The email address 'service-org-<ORG_ID>@security-center-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com ' is invalid or non-existent.`

Not sure if anyone has something similar

Answer (score 0):

Usually the said error means that resources being accessed don't have a common Service Perimeter. You may check the corresponding `resourceName` field on the audit logs. See also the following list to verify your issue:

- Make sure that all resources listed in resourceNames are within the same service perimeter.
- If the resources are in different perimeters, a [perimeter bridge](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/share-across-perimeters) is required to share resources across perimeters.
- To connect the resources' projects, especially if they are from different organizations, use an ingress/egress rule.